# Check duplicate certificates in a truststore

Tags: ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm working on import and solution to avoid duplicate certificates in a trust store.
I see that using keytool we can import same certificate multiple time by giving unique alias name.This will create duplicate certificates in a trust store and wanted to know a solution to avoid duplicate certs in the trust-store by validating during the certificate import ?

Please help..

Thanks,
KP

Comment: Code in batch. Get a list of the Certificate' Fingerprints and filter the new addition comparing the new fingerprint with the ones on the list. For sure, the batch script will be the entry point for this. I have no seen another solution.

Comment: -printcert -file <new_cert> would serve for checking the new cert file.
-list -v will print the cert into the truststore